# how can i get the coordinates from a scaled div?

Tags: javascript, math

how can i get the scaled coordinates from a resized div? What I am trying to do is draw a square over a small image (example : 320x240). The data set that tells me to draw this square actually gets its coordinates from a larger image (example : 640x480). I probably should have paid more attention in elementary school as there is probably a name for this formula.

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/265311809475444737/328765651176914944/video.mov

In the video link you can see the cars are not always in boxes. Partly because the AI isn't trained enough yet but you can see that when it does see a car the box isn't always around it. Not until it gets near the top left of the image.

Just letting me know the name of the formula required to calculate this is enough :D Or a link to a javascript method that does this would be even better :D Thanks!

Example Origin Data of a square, its coordinates and size on a 640x480 image:

`{x:34,y:25,height:30,width:30}`

How can get the info for a display image of ,for example, 320x240?

`{x:?,y:?,height:?,width:?}`

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question.

Comment: @Teemu I didn't paste the actual code because it may make things more confusing but you can see what i am doing here starting at Line 732 on the green side https://github.com/moeiscool/Shinobi/commit/dcfa74310ca8eb22083ad6ca899dc8bc1a2de80e#diff-f931e61b95d72b90363a29f1b82a63b9

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct name for this formula is *rule of three* :

```
var div={x:34,y:25,height:30,width:30};
var img={x:34,y:25,height:240,width:320}
var scale=Math.min(div.height/img.height,div.width/img.width);
img.heigth*=scale;
img.width*=scale;
```

Comment: thanks for this, i tried it and it seemed to make the squares appear in strange places with odd sizes. I found that If I just get the ratio of height and width then i can multiple the height ratio to Y and width ratio to X and it seems to properly wrap the cars.

Comment: thank you for your help, ill throw down an upvote :D

Answer (score 0):

here is a simplified version of what worked for me.

```
var redBox={x:34,y:25,height:30,width:30}
var div=$('#stream-element')
var displayHeight=div.height()
var displayWidth=div.width()
var originalHeight=480
var originalWidth=640

//get ratios                        
var widthRatio=displayWidth/originalWidth
var heightRatio=displayHeight/originalHeight

//get scaled coordinates
var newRedBoxX=redBox.x*widthRatio
var newRedBoxY=redBox.y*heightRatio
var newRedBoxWidth=redBox.width*widthRatio
var newRedBoxHeight=redBox.height*heightRatio
```

Here is where i am actually using it.
https://github.com/moeiscool/Shinobi/commit/e88d977c5aff3cbd1beb848c3c7d0762c2a50ec3